# spring boot missing log file

Tags: logging, spring-boot

I have set application.properties with:

```
logging.path = /var/log
```

and use slf4j in my controller:

```
log.info("/get-by-email: " + email);
```

My console prints it fine:

> 2015-10-23 10:03:50.636  INFO 13108 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] netgloo.controllers.UserController       : /get-by-email: haha@laugh.com

I don't have any log file generated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to create the actual folder in root.

Changed application.properties to

```
logging.path = log
```

and created the log folder in root (next to src) and it's good now.